# Should it be possible to fetch iOS bookmarks with iCloud?

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud, bookmarks

It's seems that there is a Jailbroken way to fetch them, but now using iCloud for instance, is there any a new way to get them ?

I saw nothing reading the documentation, but I may have missed something.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean Safari's bookmarks? That's not possible without jailbreaking. Each app (or group of apps by the *same* publisher) has its own container directory in iCloud, there's no way to get at another app's data.